# Power Automate Flow Error - Add Row to a Table

Tags: excel, row, power-automate

I'm struggling with a flow error for my add a row into a table flow. I created this flow a few months back and it has been working well during that time period but all of a sudden about 3 weeks ago it stopped working.

I am getting a "target session is invalid" error and it says "bad request" on the flow itself where the error is occurring.

I've tried a few things to fix this including messing with the excel sheet where the cell is supposed to be added to and changing the location of the excel file in SharePoint but nothing has worked. I've also tried completely re-writing the flow from scratch but I'm getting the same error. I've done some research into the issue and I know that there can be an issue if the excel table has more than 75 rows but none of mine have that many rows.

I've added some screenshots of the flow and the error itself. Any help is appreciated!!

[[image: flow overview][1]]
[image]

Comment: I solved my own issue. For some reason it was not working when I had the source excel file in SharePoint but it worked when I moved it to OneDrive. Not sure why but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue. For some reason it was not working when I had the source excel file in SharePoint but it worked when I moved it to OneDrive. Not sure why but it is working now.